# ¿Cómo puedo insertar imágenes de nuevas marcas o logos y sean detectadas con la anotación LOGO_DETECTION de Google Cloud Vision Api?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Estoy usando Google Cloud Vision API para detectar logos de marcas o empresas, al realizar pruebas todo funciona correctamente. Sin embargo, en la aplicación que estoy desarrollando se necesita subir imágenes o logos de marcas que no sean tan populares (**nuevas empresas, nuevos logos o nuevas marcas e**).

**Ejemplo**: se necesita que para una nueva empresa se puedan subir logos e imágenes y queden en la base de datos de google para luego poder escanear o subir una imagen y la **API REST** me de como resultado el nombre de la **nueva** empresa.

Answer (score 0):

Ahora mismo, Google Cloud Vision API no ofrece la posibilidad de añadir nuevas imágenes a los sets de datos de entrenamiento, por lo que el objetivo que buscas no puede ser conseguido con una solución "pre-entrenada" como Vision API.

El caso que presentas requeriría el desarrollo de tu propio sistema de Machine Learning (preferiblemente una red neuronal, que son especialmente útiles en el reconocimiento de imágenes), utilizando alguna herramienta como [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/). Sin embargo, esto requiere elevados conocimientos de desarrollo en esta materia, así que quizá esta solución se escapa a las posibilidades de tu proyecto. Sin embargo, como ya he comentado, a día de hoy, la Vision API de Google no ofrece la posibilidad de añadir imágenes propias a los modelos entrenados.